# Toggle checkbox - click on parent DIV element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few div elements and inside every div one checkbox.
On click this div I want to check/uncheck checkbox and add class like active or checked. Have some code if you have any idea.

```
<div class="filter">
    <div id="select_10">
       <input type="checkbox" name="what" />
       visible1
    </div>
    <div id="select_91">
       <input type="checkbox" name="ever" />
       visible2
    </div>
    <div id="select_101">
       <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" />
       visible3
    </div>    
</div>
```

using this code:

```
$(document).on("click", "div.filter div", function (event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    var id = $(this)attr('id');
    if (target.is('div#'+id+' input:checkbox')) {
        return;
    }
    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
    checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: Perfect sunny time to use `<label>` instead of `<div>`

Comment: I will check - thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

`$(this)attr('id');` should have a `.` like in

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

That's it.

---

Why using DIV and JS **when we have `<label>` for that purpose**!

```css
.filter label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  background: #eee;
  margin:5px; padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <label id="select_10">
    <input type="checkbox" name="what" />
    visible1
  </label>
  <label id="select_91">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ever" />
    visible2
  </label >
  <label id="select_101">
    <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" />
    visible3
  </label >    
</div>
```

all you need. Style label as you would for your DIV by just adding eventually `display: block;`

---

Or you can even move the inputs before the label and style the complete LABEL elements in pure CSS:

```css
.filter input{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.filter label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin:5px; padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}

.filter input:checked + label{
  background: #cf5;
}

.filter                 label:before{content: "\2610";}
.filter input:checked + label:before{content: "\2611";}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  
  <input  id="ckb_10" type="checkbox" name="what" />
  <label for="ckb_10">
    what
  </label>
  
  <input  id="ckb_91" type="checkbox" name="foo" />
  <label for="ckb_91">
    foo
  </label>
  
</div>
```

Comment: One dot and so much happiness

Comment: @TadeuszMajkowski hahahaaha I know happens to me all the time, but than I open Developer tools and I see my errors!

Comment: @TadeuszMajkowski strange my Netbeans would burn me alive if it noticed such error.

Comment: @TadeuszMajkowski you'e welcome. I've expanded my answer in the meantime, You might check the added content.

Comment: Ohhh You already add checked style - want to do it for myselft but I will check your solution :)

Comment: Very nice ! Thanks again :)